# Apache Flink local setup, practical differences between standalone JAR vs start-cluster.sh

Tags: apache-flink

So the code is the same in both approaches and it's roughly the following:

```java
StreamExecutionEnvironment env = StreamExecutionEnvironment.getExecutionEnvironment();
// prepare the topology...
env.execute();
```

The scenario is Flink running *locally* on a single machine.

### Standalone JAR

`pom.xml` (relevant bits):

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.flink</groupId>
    <artifactId>flink-core</artifactId>
    <version>1.9.0</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.flink</groupId>
    <artifactId>flink-streaming-java_2.12</artifactId>
    <version>1.9.0</version>
</dependency>
```

Run with:

```
java -cp target/My-0.0.0.jar MainClass
```

### `start-cluster.sh`

`pom.xml` (relevant bits):

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.flink</groupId>
    <artifactId>flink-core</artifactId>
    <version>1.9.0</version>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.flink</groupId>
    <artifactId>flink-streaming-java_2.12</artifactId>
    <version>1.9.0</version>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
```

Run with:

```
/path/to/flink-1.9.1/bin/flink run -c MainClass target/My-0.0.0.jar
```

---

[This](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-stable/dev/local_execution.html) documentation page states:

> The LocalExecutionEnvironment is starting the full Flink runtime, including a JobManager and a TaskManager. These include memory management and all the internal algorithms that are executed in the cluster mode.

And makes me think that there is no practical differences between the two, but I can't be sure...

Is there anything else I need to consider? Would there be any differences in terms of performance?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you have found in the documentation, there is little to no difference between the two modes.

`LocalExecutionEnvironment` will create a mini cluster with a locally running job manager, resource manager, and the configured number of task managers (local.number-taskmanager, default is 1).

If you run `start-cluster.sh`, it will spawn the same things. The number of task managers [depend on your conf/slaves though](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-release-1.9/ops/deployment/cluster_setup.html#configuring-flink) (which contains only localhost by default).

The main difference is that the `LocalExecutionEnvironment` runs all these services inside the same JVM, as it is primarily meant to be a debug tool that you run from your IDE. In cluster mode, you will end up with two different processes. Performance-wise, I'd expect no visible difference, as the main load is processed on the task managers. Only the coordination messages (as remote procedure calls) should be faster within the same JVM process.

However, be aware of subtle differences in the configuration and most importantly classloading. Since the local mode will have everything in one process, you might see more/other classes than in cluster mode. So before going to production, make sure to test it in a cluster setup. You also have no Web UI in local mode.

Comment: Another difference is that in local mode there is no configuration file to load, so you get the default configuration.

Comment: @DavidAnderson, but you can still change it programmatically right?

Comment: @cYrus, exactly you can pass your own configuration when creating the local environment.
`StreamExecutionEnvironment.createLocalEnvironment(<parallelism>, <configuration>)`
That can also be used to bring up the web ui. see `StreamExecutionEnvironment.createLocalEnvironmentWithWebUI` for a convenience wrapper.

Comment: @cYrus You can also use  `FileSystem.initialize(GlobalConfiguration.loadConfiguration("/path/to/conf/directory"));` to load flink-conf.yaml.